# Bernoulli Trials with Correlation

Tags: probability, correlation

Let $\{X_i | 1 \leq i \leq N\}$ be N Bernoulli random variables with the same success probability $p$
$$
\forall i, X_i\sim Bernoulli(p)
$$
The variables are not i.i.d, but the correlation coefficient for each pair of different variables is equal to $\rho$, and $\rho > 0$
$$
\forall i,j, i\neq j, \rho_{i,j}=\rho, \rho>0
$$

I want to find the probability that more than half of the variables succeeded, define:
$$
Y=\sum_{i=1}^{N}{X_i}
$$
Looking for:
$$
P(Y\geq \frac{N}{2})=?
$$

If the Bernoulli variables were i.i.d this could be calculated with a binomial distribution, but how can this be calculated when the variables are correlated?

Comment: Looks pretty hard, cf. https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/363129/248311

Comment: Thanks, that looks very relevant and hard indeed.

Comment: One can at least say that $P(Y\ge\alpha N)\ge\frac{p-\alpha}{1-\alpha}$ for all $0\le \alpha\le p$.

Comment: Thanks @nejimban, how do you get this bound?

Comment: @user107511 just Markov inequality. Probably one can get a tighter bound (in terms of $\rho$) with Chebyshev's,